# Not able to run cucumber test case from Intellij. Getting "Could not resolve org.testng:testng:7.7.1." exception

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng, gherkin

I have created gradle project. Here are my dependencies added in `build.gradle`

```
testImplementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '5.3.1'
    testImplementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-path', version: '5.3.1'
    testImplementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '5.3.1'
    implementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'xml-path', version: '5.3.1'
    implementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured-common', version: '5.3.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.12.1'
    compileOnly group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '5.7.6'
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '7.12.1'
```

I have created feature file, step definitions and TestRunner. Here is my TestRunner file

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-report.html"}
)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

To execute this I have created a configuration. Cucumber java as well as TestNG and select TestRunner as main class. But getting below exception

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.testng:testng:7.7.1.
     Required by:
         project : > io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:7.12.1
      > No matching variant of org.testng:testng:7.7.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'antApiElements' capability org.testng:testng-ant:7.7.1 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'antRuntimeElements' capability org.testng:testng-ant:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.testng:testng:7.7.1 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'guiceApiElements' capability org.testng:testng-guice:7.7.1 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'guiceRuntimeElements' capability org.testng:testng-guice:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.testng:testng:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
          - Variant 'junitApiElements' capability org.testng:testng-junit:7.7.1 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'junitRuntimeElements' capability org.testng:testng-junit:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.testng:testng:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.testng:testng:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
          - Variant 'yamlApiElements' capability org.testng:testng-yaml:7.7.1 declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'yamlRuntimeElements' capability org.testng:testng-yaml:7.7.1 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have these plugins in `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.commercehub.cucumber-jvm" version "0.11"

}
```

I have already removed testNG dependency. Kindly help me to understand how to execute Test cases written in Cucumber + Gradle + Intellij

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?